# Ansible Windows ACL

Tags: windows, ansible, acl

Using Ansible 2.7, I want to change ACL for a particular Windows folder, if it exists.

Here the code I use :

```
  - name: check that folder exists
    win_stat:
      path: C:\Program Files (x86)\MyFolder
    register: folderPresent

  - name: cut ACL inheritance and copy existing ones
    win_acl_inheritance:
      path: C:\Program Files (x86)\MyFolder
      state: absent
      reorganize: yes
    when: folderPresent.stat.exists

  - name: Add write right for authenticated users
    win_acl:
      path: C:\Program Files (x86)\MyFolder
      user: ThisMachine\Utilisateurs
      rights: Write
      type: allow
      state: present
      inherit: ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
      propagation: 'InheritOnly'
    when: folderPresent.stat.exists
```

The problem occurs with the win_acl command. I get : "*an error occurred when attempting to present Write permission(s) on C:\Program Files (x86)\MyFolder*", followed by a french nessage "*Impossible de traduire certaines ou toutes les références d'identité*." (that translates to *impossible to translate some or all identity references*).

The Windows machines I am dealing with are installed in French, so my assumption is that I am not specifying the ACL target user correctly.

So far I have tried many variations for the "user" parameter for the win_acl command :

- ThisMachine\Utilisateurs
- BUILTIN\Utilisateurs
- ThisMachine\Users
- S-1-5-32-545
- ...

But none of them works...

Answer (score 3):

An [Ansible bug](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/20555) affect win_acl when dealing with folders such as :

- c:\Program Files
- c:\Program Files (x86)
- c:\Windows

So the workaround that worked for me was to use a Windows command instead of the Ansible `win_acl` module :

```
win_shell: icacls 'C:/Program Files (x86)/MyFolder/' /grant '*S-1-5-11:(OI)(CI)F' /T
```

Where :

- `'C:/Program Files (x86)/MyFolder/'` target folder, using / and not \, surrounded with quoted because of the spaces inside
- `*S-1-5-1` [a well-known Windows SID](https://support.microsoft.com/fr-ch/help/243330/well-known-security-identifiers-in-windows-operating-systems) for Authenticated Users, the star starts an SID instead of a group or a user name (I was not able here to use anything else than an SID)
- `(OI)(CI)` : propagates inheritance to both files and folders
- `/T` : do it recursively on sub-folders